# how to write DDL command inside a procedure for checking and adding column in a table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How to create a procedure which will check the particular column is  present in table or not 
If not then I want to add that column in that table using  ddl command

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in a stored procedure:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns 
            WHERE Name = N'yourColumnName' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'yourTableName'))
BEGIN
-- your column exists
END
ELSE
BEGIN
--Add column
END
```